# Android alert dialog shortlist text too small

Tags: android, dialog, selection, alert

My problem is that the spinner where I can choose between Linie 1 to Linie 5 is too small. Both text and columns of the spinner are extremely small and I couldn't find a way to fix it yet. But normally outside of an alert dialog the columns of the spinner are as big as the column of the selection (the first "Linie 1" in the image below).

[image]

Java Code:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setView(promptsView);
            builder.setTitle("Linie auswählen:");
            builder.setNegativeButton( "Abbrechen", null );
            builder.setPositiveButton( "Ok", new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
            alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Layout of the promptsView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you show what is happening when your Dialog shows?

Comment: If you want to set the text bigger, just change it on the promptsView layout.

Comment: you need to use a spinner with a custom textview

Comment: right will update that shortly

Comment: ok edited it.. any tips on the custom textview?

Comment: You have to Instantiate your Spinner using view.findViewById() and then set an Adapter to it.

Comment: ok thanks will try that out tomorrow

Comment: Try custom spinner along with custom alert dialog